# how to extract a subset of time series using windows() function?

Tags: r, time-series

I used the window function to extract a subset of time series. But it is not functioning correctly sometimes. Example is shown below. Any suggestions?

```
library(Mcomp)
monthly_m1 <- subset(M1, "monthly")
x <- monthly_m1[[150]]$xx
endx <- end(x)
window(x, end=c(endx[1],endx[2]-17)) # gives the first observation in x
```

but following doesn't work

```
monthly_m1 <- subset(M1, "monthly")
y <- monthly_m1[[171]]$xx
endy <- end(y)
window(y, end=c(endy[1],endy[2]-17)) # does not give the first observation in y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first observation in each, use

```
subset(x, end=1)
subset(y, end=1)
```

Using `window` with negative end values seems to be problematic, possibly due to some rounding issues with the times.